# VB6.0 Search on Listview

Tags: sql, listview, sorting, search, vb6

My search code is working but after i deleted the string that i searched, the data in listview will go to uncertain sort. My original sort is to display first the items which are near to their expiration dates.

I have 4 fields

```
Sub LoadData()
Dim list As ListItem
Dim x As Integer
  ConnectDB
    rs.Open "Select * from Table1 Order by Expiry ASC", db, 3, 3
       Do Until rs.EOF
           Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs(0))
              For x = 1 To 3
                list.SubItems(x) = rs(x)
                  Next x
        rs.MoveNext

   Loop
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

My search code which will sort the Product name with the first letter on search bar.
and one problem, what is the SQL statement if you want to search string of words not just in 
first letter but in whole word.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
ListView1.ListItems.Clear
ConnectDB
rs.Open "Select * from Table1 where ProductName LIKE '" & txtSearch & "%'", db, 3, 3
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs(0))
            For x = 1 To 3
                list.SubItems(x) = rs(x)
        Next x
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add % symbol on beginning of search key:
"Select * from Table1 where ProductName LIKE '%" & txtSearch & "%' ORDER BY ProductName"

Comment: It works. You hit two birds in one stone. I will work now in my project. @novian Agung